# How to save Excel table as Word doc in multiple pages

Tags: pagination, ms-word, excel-2007

I have an Excel sheet whose size is 100 rows and 10 columns.
How can I save this excel sheet to MS Word doc such that:
Each page in the word doc must contain a table of consecutive 25 rows from the excel sheet.
(First page contains first 25 rows, second page contains next 25 rows etc).
Can I specify the row height, column width, Font type and Font size while exporting to Word?

Answer (score 1):

I guess a 'neat' answer is not available, or you would have heard by now! But there are several workarounds:

1. Most obvious:  Select and paste 25 rows at a time (only involves repeating 4 times!) If you want a title row/rows on each Word page then hide appropriate rows before copying.
2. Copy and paste entire table and insert 3 Page Breaks where required, or enough blank rows to force next 'block' onto the subsequent page. If that leaves borders around empty cells, reformat those rows without borders.

Both 1. and 2. allow changes to column/row spacing, font size/type etc.

1. Insert as images, 25 rows at a time (with or without headers, to suit) and either Page Break or use extra lines to get the spacing suitable.

3.will not give the flexibility of 1. and 2. (so you might want to ensure font type etc is suitable before copying) but the size of images can be increased or reduced to suit. Images also have the disadvantage that not all formatting is copied faithfully.